# Kafka: Manually producing record triggers exception in consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro

I have a consumer which polls from multiple topics. 
Until now I only produced record into these topics with Java and everything worked fine.

I use the confulent tools with avro.

Now I tried to manually produce a topic via the terminal.

I create a avro-producer with the same schema my other producer uses:

```
# Produce a record with one field
kafka-avro-console-producer \
  --broker-list 127.0.0.1:9092 --topic order_created-in \
  --property schema.registry.url=http://127.0.0.1:8081 \
  --property value.schema='{"type":"record","name":"test","fields":[{"name":"name","type":"string"},{"name":"APropertie","type":{"type":"array","items":{"type":"record","name":"APropertie","fields":[{"name":"key","type":"string"},{"name":"name","type":"string"},{"name":"date","type":"string"}]}}}]}'
```

After that I produce a record which follows the specified schema:

```
{"name": "order_created", "APropertie": [{"key": "1", "name": "testname", "date": "testdate"}]}
```

The record gets correctly produced to the topic. **But** my AvroConsumer throws an exception:

```
Polling
Polling
Polling
Polling
Polling
Polling
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition order_created-in-0 at offset 1. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id 61
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Could not find class test specified in writer's schema whilst finding reader's schema for a SpecificRecord.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any hints? 
Thanks!

Comment: Haven't used avro, but "Could not find class test specified in writer's schema" sounds like it's trying to deserialize into a class test (used in the record `name ` in the schema).

Comment: Yes. Do you know what exactly is wrong with that? In the "original" schema I used "test" as well.

Comment: Okay I think the console producer has no access to the classes `APropertie` and `AEvent` mentioned in the schema. This may be a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has something to do with the config of the producer / consumer.

Normal producers have a config like this:

```
        // normal producer
        properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "127.0.0.1:9092");
        properties.setProperty("acks", "all");
        properties.setProperty("retries", "10");
```

Avro normally adds the following properties:

```
        // avro part
        properties.setProperty("key.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty("value.serializer", KafkaAvroSerializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty("schema.registry.url", "http://127.0.0.1:8081");
        properties.setProperty("confluent.value.schema.validation", "true");
        properties.setProperty("confluent.key.schema.validation", "true");
```

These have to be included in the the console producer.